# How to set a default value from appsettings to a property on a API Model

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

How can I set a default value to a property, reading it from my appsettings.json file, on a model that is instantiated by the .NET Core 3 framework?

I've created a repo (a completely new .NET Core 3 project) where I try to illustrate the problem: https://github.com/NelsonPRSousa/dependency-injection-default-constructor

API Action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] FilteringRequestModel request)
{

    var defaultType = request.Type;

    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

Model:

```cs
public class FilteringRequestModel
{
    /* Please note that we must have a parameterless constructor, since it's the framework responsability to instatiate this object
     * when invoking this action: IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] FilteringRequestModel request)
     */

    public FilteringRequestModel()
    {
        //Type = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultTypeTopRated"];
    }

    public string Type { get; set; } = "top_rated"; // TODO: Read from appsettings
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the setting commented out in your constructor?

Comment: Because it doesn't work, it returns null

Comment: It shouldn't.  Please drop a debug point on the line where you instantiate an instance of the class and inspect the object property at that point.  You're not showing that point in your code.  The object that's being passed into the "Get" method may not have that property set.  So, start with the point where you have `var request = new FilteringRequestModel()` and step forward in your debugger from there.

Comment: I am not instantiating FilteringRequestModel. That job is .NET Core framework's responsibility when we call the Get endpoint. I have all the code here: https://github.com/NelsonPRSousa/dependency-injection-default-constructor (just a simple controller + model)

Answer (score 2):

You could use IOptions with Dependecy Injection

Update `FilteringRequestModel` class

```
public class FilteringRequestModel
{
    public FilteringRequestModel()
    {
    }

    public void Initialize(IOptions<FilteringRequestSettings> settings)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Type))
        {
            this.Type = settings.Value.Type;
        }
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Add a `FilteringRequestSettings` class

```
public class FilteringRequestSettings
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Update `appsettings.Development.json` like this

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "FilteringRequest": {
    "Type":  "foo"
  }
}
```

Update `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FilteringRequestSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("FilteringRequest"));

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Finally, update `WeatherForecastController` class like this

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] FilteringRequestModel request)
{
    request.Initialize(_settings);

    var defaultType = request.Type;

    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

***Explanation***

- You will load parameter from appsettings into
  `IOptions<FilteringRequestSettings>`
- `IOptions<FilteringRequestSettings>` will be injected into
  `WeatherForecastController`
- You will then call the `Initialize` method your `request`
  parameter with `IOptions<FilteringRequestSettings>`
- The `Initialize` method verify if the `Type` property has not already been set (from query / request). If not, it will use the value from appsettings (through `IOptions<FilteringRequestSettings>`

Comment: It's a nice workaround but, based on this solution, we are not using the default initial value in-line (the value is null when the object is instantiated). Also, we need to put some logic on the controller. I was expecting some magic in the parameter-less constructor (like getting some dependency by DI, but guess it is not possible). Btw, thank you for your fork, it helped to test it!

Comment: As the parameterless constructor is used to create the model. You can not use .NET Core default dependency injection which is based on constructor injection. Maybe you could use another DI container like autofac to use Property Injection ?

Comment: That's a solution, yes... So, with .NET Core default dependency injection is not possible, is that it?

Answer (score -1):

Used  IConfiguration for setp the appsetting varaiables

```
private readonly IConfiguration _setting;
public FilteringRequestModel(IConfiguration setting)
    {
        _setting= setting;
        
    }

public void Initialize()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Type))
    {
        this.Type = _setting.GetSection("FilteringRequest:Type").Value;
    }
}
```

this will help you for setup the default values