# How to automatically set default value of API model's property with value from appSettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a web API in Core 3.1 and I have `PagingParams` model that I will use on many controller actions. The model has `PageNumber` and `PageSize` parameters, both of which have a default value:

```
public class PagingParams
{
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must be greater than 0.")]
    public int? PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;

    [Range(1, 10000)] //TODO: Get 10000 from appsettings
    public int? PageSize { get; set; } = 10000; //TODO: Get 10000 from appsettings
}
```

The `PageSize` parameter value needs to be set to 10000 and same with the max value in its `Range` attribute. This prevents the user from getting more than 10k items per page.

I want to be able to retrieve that value from `appSettings.json` so I can modify it without republishing the  the application each time. Throughout the code I've been using [`IOptionsSnapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data) to read values from `appSettings.json`, but it appears that can't be done here because the model is required to have a parameterless constructor, resulting in the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'WebAPI.Models.PagingParams'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'pagingParams' parameter a non-null default value.

How could I set up the model so that by default the `int` is taken from appSettings and set in the two places?

This is how the class is used:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IUserRepo _userRepo;

        public MissingNamesController(IMapper mapper, IUserRepo userRepo)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _userRepo = userRepo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserDto> Get([FromQuery] UsersQueryParams queryParams, [FromQuery] PagingParams pagingParams)
        {
            IEnumerable<User> models = _userRepo.Get(queryParams, pagingParams);
            IEnumerable<UserDto> dtoModels = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDto>>(models);
            return dtoModels;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402907/how-to-set-a-default-value-from-appsettings-to-a-property-on-a-api-model), except that I want to be able to set this up so it's automated. I want to avoid calling a method each time I use the `PagingParams` class on an action and then having to manually call `ModelState.IsValid` and return the model error. With my current set up, the `Range` attribute automatically handles returning of a model error and I don't have to do anything further.

Comment: this depends on ***when*** you create/obtain an instance of the `PagingParams`, really. That's very important to achieve what you want. Presetting default values for properties is not something magical, we just instantiate the object and set the properties normally, especially when it is just an object containing data/value (not services exposed via interfaces or something injected using IoC container).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've edited my question to show where `PagingParams` is used. It's just one of the parameters of an action. I'm not sure of the specifics, but I'd guess an instance of the object is created when data is received and bound to it. May need to just write some logic and manually check `PagingParams` object's propertie's values.

Comment: well so if's pretty simple, I just tell you the mechanism, you can search for more detail. The idea is to use a ***global*** `IActionFilter` (for Razor page we have `IAsyncPageFilter`). It will have a chance to take the input arguments (of the invoked action/handler) so you can modify the `PagingParams` there ***in one place***. It's kind of a `cross-cutting concern`. The principle here is to find a point (in the execution/request flow) where you can modify your object so that you just need one place to write your (modifying) code. Here in this case `IActionFilter` is one of such points.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of using an action filter but the issue then is that I have to hardcode the name of the parameter object. So, looking at the `Get` action I provided, I'd need to use something like `filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("pagingParams").AttemptedValue` in the filter to get the object. But `"pagingParams"` is hardcoded and I'd need to always be careful to make sure every action's parameter of `PagingParams` type is called exactly `pagingParams`. Maybe there's a way to get it by type if available, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: No, you filter for the ***parameter type*** not the parameter name. It's completely feasible and not hard to implement.

Comment: Can you help me to figure out how to get it by parameter type? I'm digging around through `ActionExecutingContext` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've added the answer to help you figure it out. It's fairly simple. Actually you should have been able to solve it yourself with all I commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to conveniently have some properties initialized with some default values. The core mechanism is just simple like you instantiate an object and set its properties before it's being used in the next pipelines. There are some ways to achieve it:

- Set the properties right in the class declaration: This is not what you want because you want to populate the default values from some settings (at runtime).
- Set the properties everywhere you have the object: This means in the current context, you need the default values loaded from the settings/configuration so that you can initialize the properties.

Usually you do it the second way. However to avoid repetitive code as much as possible, we need to find a point in the pipeline (code execution - request processing flow) where you can obtain the object and initialize its properties (loaded from configuration) in one place.

It's fairly easy that in your case the `PagingParams` is not instantiated everywhere in your code, it just comes from controller actions (instantiated by model binding). So in that case we can use action filter (either `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter` works) as the point we can obtain the argument (of type `PagingParams`) and modify it in whatever way we want (initialize the properties with loaded default values from the configuration).

It's pretty simple like this:

```
public class InitPagingParamsAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var pp = context.ActionArguments.Values.OfType<PagingParams>().FirstOrDefault();
        //this means there is at least 1 PagingParams in the controller action
        //NOTE that you can get all args of PagingParams, but looks like usually 
        //there should be just 1 arg of such type (in one same controller action)
        if (pp != null)
        {
            //modify the pp here
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Startup.cs` file, you can configure the MVC middleware to register the global action filter. Without doing that, you need to decorate the attribute `InitPagingParamsAttribute` on the controller or action method you want.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    //...
    services.AddMvc(o => {
        o.Filters.Add<InitPagingParamsAttribute>();
    });
    //...
}
```

NOTE: you can inject your `IOptionsSnapshot` in the `InitPagingParamsAttribute` constructor. So you can load the default values from the configuration there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just couldn't figure out how to get action parameter by type and I appreciate your solution and explanation!